# Add comments/remarks to .gitattributes

Tags: git, comments, gitattributes

Is it possible to add comments or remarks to a .gitattributes file?

If yes, how exactly do comment lines look like?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`# This is a comment!`

in .gitattributes.

Comment: Thanks. Is this documented somewhere? I couldn't find it.

Comment: A line starting with # serves as a comment. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first hash for patterns that begin with a hash. From: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: @tehp That's gitignore not gitattributes

Answer (score 6):

Documented in https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes :

> That is, a pattern followed by an attributes list, separated by whitespaces. Leading and trailing whitespaces are ignored. Lines that begin with # are ignored. Patterns that begin with a double quote are quoted in C style. When the pattern matches the path in question, the attributes listed on the line are given to the path.